# Scrollview of whole page is not working when I added Tap to zoom view(Image) functionality in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Scrollview of whole page is not working when I added Tap to zoom view(Image) functionality in xamarin iOS.

I have two scrollview-one is using for tap to zoom functionality and another scroll-scroll2 which is used to scroll the whole details page.This scrooll2 is not working but Tap to Zoom is working fine.

Comment: Could you add more details to the question? May be share code snippet

Comment: i shared my code snippet in answer box

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView = new UIScrollView(
         new CGRect(0, 80,View.Frame.Width
                    , View.Frame.Height -200));
        View.AddSubview(scrollView);

        scroll2.ScrollEnabled = true;
        scroll2.ContentSize = new CGSize(0f, 1760f);
        scrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
```

ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(GlobalVar.imgpath + travelerlistdetail.orderDetails.product_image)
                    .Retry(3, 200)
                    .DownSample(100, 100)
                            .Into(ImgProd);

```
            //scrollView.ContentSize = ImgProd.Size;
            scrollView.AddSubview(ImgProd);
            scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 0.9f;
            scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
            //scrollView.PinchGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
            //await Task.Delay(2000);
            //scrollView.ContentSize = ImgProd.Image.Size;


            scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return ImgProd; };

            UITapGestureRecognizer doubletap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnDoubleTap)
            {
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 // double tap
            };
            scrollView.AddGestureRecognizer(doubletap);
```

private void OnDoubleTap(UIGestureRecognizer gesture)
        {
            scroll2.ScrollEnabled = false;
            scrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            if (scrollView.ZoomScale > 1)
                scrollView.SetZoomScale(0.25f, true);
            else
                scrollView.SetZoomScale(3f, true);
        }

scroll2 is total page's scroll and scrollview is the imageview scroll when zoom in